# Can I title my project "myself and the others"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I need to give a tilte to a project with my students.
Is it grammatical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles of any sort are seldom grammatical. Frequently, like your suggested title, they lack verbs. They are not sentences or even clauses. They are just a word or words indicating the contents of a project, an essay, a book or whatever. That's the first thing to say.

So, you can entitle your project whatever you like. It's not a question of whether it's grammatical.

However, whether the title is suitable is another matter altogether. What it ought to do is to point to the contents or results of your project. Do you think that it succeeds in doing that?

Moreover, there is a grammatical point that arises. It's common to hear native English speakers say things like: **Myself and my friend did.....** They never say **Myself did...**. But they seem to think that it's okay to use **Myself** as the subject of a sentence as long as it's followed by some other person or persons. And it's wrong.

The word **myself** is a reflexive pronoun. It is properly used to refer back to someone, as in: **I did it myself**. But you can't say: **Myself did it.**

So although your suggested title is not a sentence, it does raise a question about the use of **myself**. It's not wrong. It's just a question mark? The same would be true for: **Me and the others**.

But if you feel that it conveys what you want to say, by all means use it. However, use appropriate capitals: **Myself and the Others**.